# How to set options for volumes specified in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I can set volume options when creating a volume:

```sh
$ docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=tmpfs \
    --opt device=tmpfs \
    --opt o=size=100m,uid=1000 \
    foo
```

or when I run a container with a `--mount` flag:

```sh
$ docker run \
    --mount 'type=volume,src=<VOLUME-NAME>,dst=<CONTAINER-PATH>,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=nfs,volume-opt=device=<nfs-server>:<nfs-path>,"volume-opt=o=addr=<nfs-address>,vers=4,soft,timeo=180,bg,tcp,rw"'
    <IMAGE>
```

But how to set options for volumes created in Dockerfile?:

```
FROM ubuntu
VOLUME /myvol
```

Looking at the docs, I can only see a flag for setting just a volume driver:

> ```
> --volume-driver       Optional volume driver for the container
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In general, if there are "options" for things you might specify in a Dockerfile, you can't set them there.  For a `VOLUME` you can't specify any specific host path , named volume, or device; for an `EXPOSE`d port you can't specify that it be published on a specific host interface; and so on.

In most cases I'd suggest avoiding a Dockerfile `VOLUME` declaration, since it mostly has only confusing side effects (notably, preventing any later `RUN` command from modifying that directory).  You will always need to use a `docker run -v` or similar option to mount a named volume into the container, and that doesn't need a matching `VOLUME` in the image.

If you do `docker run -v` to explicitly mount something on a directory declared as a `VOLUME`, that mount replaces the implicitly created anonymous volume.